# Reading Rich Text Character and Block Formatting

Tags: qt, richtext, qgraphicstextitem

I have rich text items implemented using `QGraphicsTextItem`

To set font size, for example:

```
void set (int fontSize) { 
    QTextCursor _cursor = textCursor();
    QTextCharFormat _format;
    _format.setFontPointSize(fontSize);
    _cursor.mergeCharFormat(_format);
    setTextCursor(_cursor); }
```

A lot more complicated is to read the font size.
Assuming I have a selection, I must iterate through the document, through all `QTextBlock`, `QTextFragment`, reading the `QTextCharFormat` ...
But the simple option, if there is no selection, just reading the font size at cursor:

```
int get () {
    return textCursor().charFormat().fontPointSize(); }
```

This works, but I found 3 issues:

1) Setting font size by `QGraphicsTextItem` properties:

```
QFont f = font();
f.setPointSize(20);
setFont(f);
```

this returns 0 by my `get` function above. To set the font size for the entire item, I have to use the same method as in the `set` function.
Shouldn't the `setFont` method set a font that can be read from the `QTextCursor` ?

2) `setHtml` can set formatting - but I don't see any way to read that formatting
How can I read the rich text formatting from an html fragment ? Is the only posiblity, parsing the html ?

3) (my current stumbling block)
Copy formatted text from an outside source and paste in the `QGraphicsTextItem` seems to maintain the formatting of the source - but how can I read that formatting ?
The `get` method above reads font size 0 if the text was pasted from outside.
    `font().pointSize()` always returns 8. (I have not set it so I imagine that is a default)
Is there another method to read the text format ?
is the clipboard text formatted using html ?

How can I find the font size (or any other formatting) from the pasted text ?

(The same questions apply to block formatting, like alignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of your problems could be solved by getting the `QTextDocument` for your `QGraphicsTextItem` object and work with it. `QTextDocument` and its methods (like [QTextFormat::property(int propertyId)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextformat.html#property)) can help you to get a lot of [properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html#Property-enum) for your text.

1) If you set the size using the `QFont` object, you should get the size using the same way.

2) When you set the text using html, `QGraphicsTextItem::font()` is not useful so you need to get the `QTextDocument` and use their functions instead.

3) Same as 2. I think... because I don't have your code to test it :)

Well, here you have a code as an example. I hope this answer helps you.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextCharFormat>
#include <QFont>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QTextBlock>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    /* ITEM 1 */
    QGraphicsTextItem* item_1  = new QGraphicsTextItem("QGraphicsTextItem 1");
    item_1->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    QFont f = item_1->font();
    f.setPointSize(30);
    item_1->setFont(f);

    qDebug() << "textCursor().position() (returns 0): " <<
                item_1->textCursor().position();
    qDebug() << "textCursor().charFormat().fontPointSize() (returns 0): " <<
                item_1->textCursor().charFormat().fontPointSize();
    qDebug() << "font().pointSize() (returns 30 - OK!): " <<
                item_1->font().pointSize();

    QTextDocument* doc = item_1->document();
    f = doc->defaultFont();
    qDebug() << "pointSize (returns 30 - OK!): " << f.pointSize();

    scene.addItem(item_1);

    /* ITEM 2 */
    QGraphicsTextItem* item_2  = new QGraphicsTextItem();
    item_2->setPos(0, 50);
    item_2->setHtml("<html><head/><body><p>"
                    "<span style=\"font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\">QGraphics</span>"
                    "<span style=\"font-size:24pt; font-weight:600;\">TextItem 2</span>"
                    "</p></body></html>");

    qDebug() << "font().pointSize() (returns 8, the default value): "
             << item_2->font().pointSize();

    doc = item_2->document();
    f = doc->defaultFont();
    qDebug() << "pointSize (returns 8, the default value): " << f.pointSize();

    QVector<QTextFormat> formats = doc->allFormats();
    QVectorIterator<QTextFormat> i(formats);
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        QTextFormat format = i.next();
        if (format.property(QTextFormat::FontPointSize).isValid())
            qDebug() << "format.property (returns 14 or 24): " <<
                        format.property(QTextFormat::FontPointSize).toInt();
    }

    /*
     * Get the block of text. In this example, we only have one block, but
     * two text fragments (see below)
     */
    QTextBlock text_block = item_2->document()->findBlock(1);
    QTextBlock::iterator it;

    for (it = text_block.begin(); !(it.atEnd()); ++it) {
        QTextFragment currentFragment = it.fragment();
        if (currentFragment.isValid())
            qDebug() << "currentFragment.text(): " << currentFragment.text();
            qDebug() << "currentFragment.charFormat().font().pointSize() "
                        "(returns 14 or 24, depending on"
                        "the current text fragment): " <<
                        currentFragment.charFormat().font().pointSize();
    }

    scene.addItem(item_2);

    view.setFixedSize(640, 480);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, so basically it is impossible to implement rich text with user interaction - using cursor position, selection and so on - with any html or any clipboard input, that is what I understand. Since that is what I have to do: implement rich text editing, the only way then is to disable any html formatting and only allow plain text paste. Is that true ? Or do I understand your answer wrong ?

Comment: My code... is gigantic... but I inserted the relevant functions, to set the font size (at cursor point so new text will have that font size) or for a selected text fragment - and also to get the font at cursor position.

Comment: Your code answers my question (2) - and also confirms my statement from (1) - except, there seems to be only a way to get all formats in the entire document. There is no way to get it at a specific point (e.g. position) or for a specific range (selection - from position a to position b).

Comment: I still find it confusing, that for 3 different methods of setting text formatting (setting font globally, html formatting, and `QTextCursor`+`QTextCharFormat` for rich text), there are 3 different methods of reading it, each incompatible with any of the others, each completely unable to read anything that any other method has set - and there may be more methods that I have not discovered.

Comment: Again, the key is to use the class `QTextDocument` + `QTextCursor`. If you have a `QTextCursor`, you could iterate over its `QTextBlock` and get the information for each `QTextFragment`. If you need the fragment for the selected text, you can use `QTextCursor::selection()`. In my opinion, use or not HTML makes no difference to me when the aim is to retrieve information about characters in the text. I've updated my answer. Now we have a rich text with two text blocks and also some lines of code to iterate over those text blocks. BTW, interesting questions! :)